# Multi Vendor Extension for Magento?

Tags: magento-1.9

I am looking for a flexible Multi vendor marketplace extension for magento that does not require users to pay for any subscription plans or alternatively that I can have access to the codes and manipulate the functionality?

Comment: I currently have the MVM marketplace extension but it has proven difficult to get it to automatically attach user to plans at registration and to have it not require user to make payments.

Comment: hakimkal you can use multi vendor marketplace extension with sellergroup addon for this purpose https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace.html
https://store.webkul.com/Magento-Marketplace-Seller-Groups.html

Answer (score -1):

Magento is complicated compared to other open source. You can try to find out another plugins in opercart.